# String to date (Invalid format)

Tags: java, date, calendar, jodatime

I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to convert my String dates to a real date, because this seemed like the easiest solution to do this. I am using the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object to do this;

```
 new DateTime(strValue);
```

But when inserting some formats it throws me the exception;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:56:02 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 19:59:01 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:52:02 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 17:05:20 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 19:09:28 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 15:01:02 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 23:48:33 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 17:24:20 GMT"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sun, 29 Sep 2002 11:13:10 GMT"
```

Is there a way to solve this, or should I use something else instead of DateTime.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That constructor is not some kind of universal date-time string interpreting engine.  It expects variants of a regular ISO date defined as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ`.

You will need to define a format string that describes your format that can then be parsed from.  It would be something like `EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz`
[javadoc here!](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: @Affe: Shouldn't the `YYYY` part in `EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz` be small letters (`yyyy`)?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the default parser you're using here expects [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted time, which this isn't. Otherwise you need to make your own [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
    "Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:56:02 GMT" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
)
```

> 2002-09-30T01:56:02Z

## RFC 1123

The format of your strings such as `Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:56:02 GMT` is defined in the outmoded standards [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) & [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822).

By the way, this is a terrible format. When serializing date-time values to text, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats instead. You will find newer standards and protocols adopting ISO 8601 formats nowadays.

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The java.time class `DateTimeFormatter` has a built-in formatter for this archaic format: [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
String input = "Mon, 30 Sep 2002 01:56:02 GMT";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
```

Use that formatter to instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + output );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jtPLY0).

> zdt.toString(): 2002-09-30T01:56:02Z

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).