# JodaTime - IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon, 29 Oct 2018 15:17:19 +0000"

Tags: java, android, jodatime, illegalargumentexception

I'm receiving a crash from a single device when it tries to parse a date

```
class DateTimeUtils {
  public static DateTime toDateTime(String value) {
     return DateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"));
  }
}
```

Stack trace

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon, 29 Oct 2018 15:17:19 +0000"
   at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
   at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:160)
   at com.example.app.DateTimeUtils.toDateTime(DateTimeUtils.java:58)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012454/string-to-date-invalid-format check this one

Comment: @MartinLund OP is already specifying the format.

Comment: Which device is that?

Comment: @TheWanderer OnePlus 5 A5000 with Android 8.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting the locale same as locale of the date to be parsed (in this case US). The device on which crash was happening had different one.

```
DateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.US));
```